# Orbeon XForms - HowTo: Copy value of repeater field via Trigger

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

I have an XForm which contains a repeater for rendering a table. Each row of the table has a trigger. When the trigger is activated I want to take the value of one of the cells in my table, for the current row, and copy that value to another instance

```
<xh:table class="dataTable">
    <xh:tr>
        <xh:th>Date</xh:th>
        <xh:th>Copy?</xh:th>
    </xh:tr>

    <xf:repeat nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')/Pathology/*:TimeSeriesStructure[*:Type/*:TypeId='ALB']/*:DataPoint">
        <xh:tr>
            <xh:td>
               <xf:output ref="*:DateTime"/>
            </xh:td>
           <xh:td>
               <xf:trigger xxf:modal="true">
                    <xf:label>Select</xf:label>
                    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                         <xf:setvalue bind="target-bind">
                            <xf:output ref="*:DateTime"/>
                         </xf:setvalue>
                    </xf:action>
               </xf:trigger>
           </xh:td>
      </xh:tr>
   </xf:repeat>
 </xh:table>
```

In this case I want to copy the value of the Date field to the item bound by "target-bind" when the trigger is activated.

Currently (as above), the existing value (element bound via "target-bind") is deleted, but the new value (*:DateTime) is not copied across.

Answer (score 0):

Now resolved. The problem was the target-bind in the setvalue section. The presence of this meant that the output was looking for a subnode of the binding called DateTime. When it should be looking at the node that the repeater is rendering. Moving it out to a variable and accessing it this way solved the problem

```
<xh:table class="dataTable">
     <xh:tr>
    <xh:th>Date</xh:th>
    <xh:th>Copy?</xh:th>
</xh:tr>

<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')/Pathology/*:TimeSeriesStructure[*:Type/*:TypeId='ALB']/*:DataPoint">
    <xf:var name="itemVal" value="*:DateTime"/>        
    <xh:tr>
        <xh:td>
           <xf:output value="$itemVal"/>
        </xh:td>
       <xh:td>
           <xf:trigger xxf:modal="true">
                <xf:label>Select</xf:label>
                <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                     <xf:setvalue bind="target-bind" value="$itemVal" />
                </xf:action>
           </xf:trigger>
       </xh:td>
  </xh:tr>
```